# PHP - Best practices evaluating IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Consider the following

```
if(!count($_POST)) { echo 'something'; }
if(empty($_POST)) { echo 'something'; }
if(!$_POST) { echo 'something'; }
```

Each line above pretty much do the same thing.  I haven't been particular about which one I use.  Should I be more particular?  Does it really matter?

Comment: just a reminder there is no "is_empty()" function, it's just "empty()"

Comment: Are you asking specifically about checking $_POST or arrays in general?  $_POST is a bit of a special case since it's always going to be defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // POST request
}
```

Comment: That's what I use! And I also check to make sure my forms/arguments are there and safe as well.

Comment: Oh, and I think the "correct" way would be to have 'post' lowercase (as if it really matters).

Comment: The correct way for POST in $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is 'POST' (upper case), just as it is upper case in the HTTP header.

Comment: @d03boy: HTTP request method strings are case-sensitive and are always uppercase. Lowercase 'post' will not (or should not) work.

Answer (score 1):

I've always preferred using `empty()` since it returns True if the argument variable is either unset or set but evaluates to False (which an empty array will). That saves a step in my mind and replaces the equivalent `if(!isset($_POST) || !$_POST) { echo 'something'; }` that chaos just mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if the request was made using a POST request, then
checking $_SERVER['request_method'] is the way to go.

If you want to find out if an array is empty, there are some differences:

- empty()

Empty will check if a variable is "empty". PHP considers the following values to be empty:

```
*  "" (an empty string)
* 0 (0 as an integer)
* "0" (0 as a string)
* NULL
* FALSE
* array() (an empty array)
* var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Empty is a language construct, which means you can't use it as a callback, so the following will fail:

```
$var = array(); call_user_func('empty', $var);
```

It also only checks variables, so the following will fail with a fatal too:

```
if (empty(array()) { // do something }
```

It is also faster than count, but this shouldn't make you consider it over the others.

- count()

Count is a "normal" function, it will first cast the parameter to an array, and check if it is empty. Personally I would use this to check empty arrays.

- if ($value) { // do something }

This differs a little from count, because $value here will be cast to a boolean, and because empty arrays cast to false, it will achieve the same result as count.

There is a very big gotcha involved because of casting:

```
$var = ''; // empty string
var_dump(empty($var)); // returns true
var_dump(count($var)); // returns false
```